# I don't know why the qemu-system error occurs

Tags: qemu

[image]

Why does an error appear as shown in the picture?

Is the command wrong?

Before entering that command, I entered the following:

1. apt-get update -y
2. Download vmlinux-3.2.0-4-4kc-malta or debian_wheez_mips_standard_qcow2 using wget command

Comment: qemu-system-* doesn't have option `-redir`. It has `hostfwd` and `guestfwd` parameters for the `-netdev` option, see https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/invocation.html#hxtool-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -redir option was removed in QEMU 3.1: https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/about/removed-features.html#redir-removed-in-3-1

You need to update the command line to use the newer syntax instead.